# Angular 6 data binding issues

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just moved form Angular JS 1.6 to Angular 6, while creating a app in  Angular 6 `[(ngModel)]="number1"` directive is used for 2 way data binding. As soon as it is used my component stops rendering and if i use `(ngModel)` the component renders but model variable binds no data. 
If i add this code in my component TS code `public number1: number = 22;`, the value is never data binded.
My version of typescript is 2.9 and it does takes this code `let we = "Hello"` and throws an error "Unexpected Token."
Does Angular creates variables just like Angular JS, like we only write a variable in HTML binded with ng-Model, that variable also gets added to $scope object, does the same happen in Angular 6.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.scss']
 })

 export class CalculatorComponent {

  //var foo = 'Hello TypeScript!';
  public number1: number = 22;
  public number2: number = 22;
  public result: number;

  public add() {
    alert(this.number1);
    alert(this.number2);
    this.result = this.number1 + this.number2;
    }

  }


<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>
            Calculator component
        </h2> 
    </div>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="operation">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input  type="number"  placeholder="number" [(ngModel)]="number1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input   type="number" placeholder="number" [(ngModel)]="number2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <button class="button" (click)="add()">
                                Add 
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="result">
                    <span>
                        Result : {{result}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the component.ts code and compoent.html code in here?

Comment: could you add the component code?

Comment: done basically i am following https://code.tutsplus.com/series/beginners-guide-to-angular-4--cms-1244

Comment: `As soon as it is used my component stops rendering` Is an error thrown or what? Have you the `FormsModule` imported?

Comment: I donot see any issue with your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-working?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html It is probably something else that is causing the error

Comment: no error in cli. FormsModule not imported. Nothing was mention for this in this article https://code.tutsplus.com/series/beginners-guide-to-angular-4--cms-1244

Comment: Import the FormsModule to your app-module. It should throw error in console though. Have you checked that?

Comment: You can follow the official tutorial... here for example it is mentioned that `FormsModule` is needed when using `ngModel` https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1

Comment: I updated my answer, check if it has anything useful for your problem :) @user5740953

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you importing **FormsModule** in your app.module.ts?

Like `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports:[ ..., FormsModule ]
  ...
})
```

> **Important** : For ngModel in **multiple input fields**

Also when you are using **more than 1 input** element with **ngModel**, you have to **use** `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

So for your example it will be like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>
            Calculator component
        </h2> 
    </div>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="operation">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input  type="number"  placeholder="number" [(ngModel)]="number1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input   type="number" placeholder="number" [(ngModel)]="number2" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <button class="button" (click)="add()">
                                Add 
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="result">
                    <span>
                        Result : {{result}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-js-databinding)

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps,

1.Import '@angular/forms' inside your app.module.

> `import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';`

2. Add 'FormsModule' into @NgModule Export Array in app.module

> ```
>   @NgModule({
>   declarations: [..
>   ],
>   imports: [
>     FormsModule
>   ],
> })
> ```

Answer (score -1):

When you use ngModel, you need to include name attribute on your controls.

Comment: There's no need to use name attribute if using `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: When using the ngModel within <form> tags, you'll also need to supply a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent form under that name.